# android check if table is empty

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i working sqllite.i successfully created database and i can add/remove/update in my database
now i want to write function to check if table is empty.if table is empty show Empty toast message else another toast message
i wrote some code but awlays Toast message is empty
this is a my code

```
public boolean checkForTables(){
    boolean hasTables = false;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        hasTables=false;
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        hasTables=true;
    }

    cursor.close();
    }
    return hasTables;


}
```

and i check this function in another activity,but as i said always toas message is Empty

```
if(helper.checkForTables())
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

what am i doing wrong if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: FYI: `checkForTables` should be named `isTableEmpy` and `hasTables` should be named `hasRecords`. For readability (and logic) sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nested the if statements in the wrong way. This way, assuming the rest is correct, should works:

```
public boolean checkForTables(){
    boolean hasTables = false;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
        hasTables=true;
        cursor.close();
    } 

    return hasTables;
}
```

BTW, performing a SELECT COUNT(*) should be more efficient:

```
public boolean checkForTables(){

  db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

  if(cursor != null){

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int count = cursor.getInt(0);

    if(count > 0){
      return true;
    }

    cursor.close();
  } 

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if` condition is wrong, try this:

```
public boolean checkForTables(){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistiped your brackets:

```
if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
    hasTables=false;
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    hasTables=true;
}

cursor.close();
}
```

to this:

```
if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
    hasTables=false;
}
else if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    hasTables=true;
}

cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select count(*) from +TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int count= cursor.getInt(0);

if(count == 0){
    hasTables=false;
}
else if(count > 0){
    hasTables=true;
}
```